# don`t know hot to validate textarea in my form with js

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am new in JS and now i am doing a form validation from FrontEnd but i get this problem with the textarea validation and i am kind stuck.... my question is how to integrate the validation of textarea to this code below:
my form

> ```
>     <form action="" class="formulario" id="formulario">
>     <div class="formulario__grupo" id="grupo__nombre">
>         <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
>             <input type="text" class="formulario__input" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre_">
>         </div>
>         <p class="formulario__input-error">El usuario tiene que ser de 4 a 16 dígitos y solo puede contener numeros, letras y guion
> ```
>
> bajo.
>
> ```
>     <div class="formulario__grupo" id="grupo__correo">
>         <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
>             <input type="email" class="formulario__input" name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="Correo_">
>         </div>
>         <p class="formulario__input-error">El correo solo puede contener letras, numeros, puntos, guiones y guion bajo.</p>
>     </div>
>
>     <div class="formulario__grupo" id="grupo__telefono">
>         <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
>             <input type="text" class="formulario__input" name="telefono" id="telefono"  placeholder="Telefono_">
>         </div>
>         <p class="formulario__input-error">El telefono solo puede contener numeros, comenzar con 569</p>
>     </div>
>     <div class="formulario__grupo" id="grupo__mensaje">
>         <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
>             <textarea type="text" name="mensaje" id="mensaje" placeholder="MENSAJE_" rows="3"></textarea>
>         </div>
>         <p class="formulario__input-error">test</p>
>     </div>
>
>     <!-- <textarea placeholder="MENSAJE_" rows="3" ></textarea> -->
>
>     <div class="formulario__mensaje" id="formulario__mensaje">
>         <p><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> <b>Error:</b> Por favor rellena el formulario correctamente. </p>
>     </div>
>
>     <div class="formulario__grupo formulario__grupo-btn-enviar">
>         <button type="submit" class="formulario__btn">Enviar</button>
>         <p class="formulario__mensaje-exito" id="formulario__mensaje-exito">¡Gracias! el formulario fue enviado
> ```
>
> exitosamente
>
> ```
> and the JS:
>
>         const formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');
>     const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#formulario input');
>     
>     const expresiones = {
>         nombre: /^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\s]{1,40}$/, 
>       correo: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/,
>       telefono: /^\d{9,13}$/
>     }
>     
>     const campos = {
>         nombre: false,
>       correo: false,
>       telefono: false
>     }
>     
>     const validarFormulario = (e) => {
>       switch (e.target.name) {
>             case "nombre":
>                 validarCampo(expresiones.nombre, e.target, 'nombre');
>             break;
>           case "correo":
>               validarCampo(expresiones.correo, e.target, 'correo');
>           break;
>           case "telefono":
>               validarCampo(expresiones.telefono, e.target, 'telefono');
>           break;
>       }
>     }
>     
>     const validarCampo = (expresion, input, campo) => {
>       if(expresion.test(input.value)){
>           document.getElementById(`grupo__${campo}`).classList.remove('formulario__grupo-incorrecto');
>           document.getElementById(`grupo__${campo}`).classList.add('formulario__grupo-correcto');
>           document.querySelector(`#grupo__${campo} .formulario__input-error`).classList.remove('formulario__input-error-activo');
>           campos[campo] = true;
>       } else {
>           document.getElementById(`grupo__${campo}`).classList.add('formulario__grupo-incorrecto');
>           document.getElementById(`grupo__${campo}`).classList.remove('formulario__grupo-correcto');
>           document.querySelector(`#grupo__${campo} .formulario__input-error`).classList.add('formulario__input-error-activo');
>           campos[campo] = false;
>       }
>     }
>     
>     
>     inputs.forEach((input) => {
>       input.addEventListener('keyup', validarFormulario);
>       input.addEventListener('blur', validarFormulario);
>     });
>     
>     formulario.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
>       e.preventDefault();
>     
>       const terminos = document.getElementById('terminos');
>       if(campos.nombre && campos.correo && campos.telefono ){
>           formulario.reset();
>     
>           document.getElementById('formulario__mensaje-exito').classList.add('formulario__mensaje-exito-activo');
>           setTimeout(() => {
>               document.getElementById('formulario__mensaje-exito').classList.remove('formulario__mensaje-exito-activo');
>           }, 5000);
>     
>           document.querySelectorAll('.formulario__grupo-correcto').forEach((icono)
> ```
>
> => {
> icono.classList.remove('formulario__grupo-correcto');
> });
> }
> // else if(campos.nombre !== '' || campos.correo !== '' || campos.telefono !== '' ){
> //     document.getElementById('formulario__mensaje').classList.remove('formulario__mensaje-activo');
> // }
> else {
> document.getElementById('formulario__mensaje').classList.add('formulario__mensaje');
> setTimeout(() => {
> document.getElementById('formulario__mensaje').classList.remove('formulario__mensaje-exito-activo');
> }, 3000);
> }
> });
> The CSS:
> .formulario__container {
> margin: 60px 0px;
> /* validation style */
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario {
> margin: 20px 0px;
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario_box {
> background-color: #355CA0;
> padding: 2rem 3rem 1rem;
> border-radius: 15px;
> max-width: 1000px;
> display: block;
> margin: auto;
> position: relative;
> }
> @media (min-width: 740px) {
> .formulario__container .formulario_box {
> background-color: #355CA0;
> padding: 2rem 5rem 1rem;
> border-radius: 15px;
> max-width: 1000px;
> display: block;
> margin: auto;
> }
> }
> .formulario__container .titulo h4 {
> color: #fff;
> font-size: 30px;
> line-height: 37px;
> font-weight: 400;
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario__grupo-input {
> position: relative;
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario__input {
> width: 100%;
> padding: 5px 8px;
> margin: 8px 0;
> display: inline-block;
> border: 1px solid #fff;
> border-radius: 10px;
> box-sizing: border-box;
> background-color: #355CA0;
> color: #fff;
> font-size: 16px;
> transition: 0.3s ease all;
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario__input:focus {
> border: 3px solid #0075FF;
> outline: none;
> box-shadow: 3px 0px 30px rgba(163, 163, 163, 0.4);
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario__input ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
> color: #fff;
> font-size: 16px !important;
> line-height: 19px;
> font-weight: 400;
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario__input :-moz-placeholder {
> color: #fff;
> font-size: 16px !important;
> line-height: 19px;
> font-weight: 400;
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario__input ::-moz-placeholder {
> color: #fff;
> font-size: 16px !important;
> line-height: 19px;
> font-weight: 400;
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario__input :-ms-input-placeholder {
> color: #fff;
> font-size: 16px !important;
> line-height: 19px;
> font-weight: 400;
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario__input-error {
> font-size: 12px;
> margin-bottom: 0;
> display: none;
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario__input-error-activo {
> display: block;
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario__validacion-estado {
> position: absolute;
> right: 10px;
> bottom: 15px;
> z-index: 100;
> font-size: 16px;
> opacity: 0;
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario__grupo-terminos,
> .formulario__container .formulario__mensaje,
> .formulario__container .formulario__grupo-btn-enviar {
> grid-column: span 2;
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario__mensaje {
> height: 45px;
> line-height: 45px;
> background: #F66060;
> padding: 0 15px;
> border-radius: 3px;
> display: none;
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario__mensaje-activo {
> display: block;
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario__mensaje p {
> margin: 0;
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario__grupo-btn-enviar {
> display: flex;
> flex-direction: column;
> align-items: center;
> }
> .formulario__container input[type=nombre],
> .formulario__container input[type=email],
> .formulario__container input[type=tel] {
> width: 100%;
> padding: 5px 8px;
> margin: 8px 0;
> display: inline-block;
> border: 1px solid #fff;
> font-size: 16px !important;
> border-radius: 10px;
> box-sizing: border-box;
> background-color: #355CA0;
> color: #fff;
> }
> .formulario__container ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
> color: #fff;
> font-size: 16px !important;
> line-height: 19px;
> font-weight: 400;
> }
> .formulario__container :-moz-placeholder {
> color: #fff;
> font-size: 16px !important;
> line-height: 19px;
> font-weight: 400;
> }
> .formulario__container ::-moz-placeholder {
> color: #fff;
> font-size: 16px !important;
> line-height: 19px;
> font-weight: 400;
> }
> .formulario__container :-ms-input-placeholder {
> color: #fff;
> font-size: 16px !important;
> line-height: 19px;
> font-weight: 400;
> }
> .formulario__container textarea {
> width: 100%;
> padding: 5px 8px;
> margin: 8px 0;
> display: inline-block;
> border: 1px solid #fff;
> border-radius: 10px;
> box-sizing: border-box;
> background-color: #355CA0;
> color: #fff;
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario__btn {
> display: block;
> margin: auto;
> margin-top: 20px;
> background-color: #fff;
> color: #355CA0;
> border: none;
> padding: 6px 32px;
> border-radius: 7px;
> font-size: 15px;
> cursor: pointer;
> transition: 0.1s ease all;
> }
> @media (min-width: 740px) {
> .formulario__container .formulario__btn {
> display: block;
> margin: auto;
> margin-top: 20px;
> background-color: #fff;
> color: #355CA0;
> border: none;
> padding: 12px 35px;
> border-radius: 15px;
> font-size: 28px;
> }
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario__mensaje-exito {
> font-size: 14px;
> font-weight: 500;
> color: #fff;
> display: none;
> position: absolute;
> bottom: 10px;
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario__mensaje-exito-activo {
> display: block;
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario__grupo-correcto .formulario__validacion-estado {
> color: #1ed12d;
> opacity: 1;
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario__grupo-incorrecto .formulario__label {
> color: #bb2929;
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario__grupo-incorrecto .formulario__validacion-estado {
> color: #bb2929;
> opacity: 1;
> }
> .formulario__container .formulario__grupo-incorrecto .formulario__input {
> border: 3px solid #bb2929;
> }

Hope you could help me

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear
If you want to validate the user input to match a specified format you should use Regex
For example you want a user email address should be a valid one and not just any string,you can either do html 5 input validation which involves adding an attribute type with the value "email" which automatically validates it or use Regular expression in JavaScript, check mdn web docs for more details on regex
Or perhaps you just want to validate the length??

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer could have been a comment

Comment: My bad, didn't know